Ruff ignore F401
I am working with VScode and python. I installed ruff because I really like it, but thee one thing I don't like is the F401 error, which basically automatically removes the unused libraries when I try to include them in my main files.
For instance, if I try to go from this:
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel

to this,
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, HTTPException, status
from pydantic import BaseModel

the status package gets automatically removed before I even scroll down to start using it on the code. This is counterintuitive and super cumbersome. The error I get is this:
"status" is not accessedPylance
`fastapi.status` imported but unusedRuff (F401)

I included this line on my pyproject.toml file:
[tool.ruff.lint]
ignore = ["E501", "F401"]

but it keeps happening all the same. It does not work.
Can somebody give me any clues on how to get rid of this functionality? I would appreciate it a lot!
Thanks in advance!
extent:
My folder structure is like this:
MY-PROJ-FOLDER
│
├── .git
├── .github
├── .pytest_cache
├── .venv
├── .vscode
├── dist
├── garbish_code
├── src
├── tests
│   └── tests_main.py
├── .dockerignore
├── .gitignore
├── .python-version
├── compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── multistage.Dockerfile
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── ruff.toml
├── run_compose.sh
└── run.sh

and my settings are:
{
    // Python settings
    "python.analysis.autoSearchPaths": true,
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportMissingImports": "none"
    },
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/src"
    ],
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python",
    // Test settings
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/tests",
    "python.testing.pytestPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/pytest",
    "python.testing.autoTestDiscoverOnSaveEnabled": true,
}


Are you sure the pyproject.toml file is actually being used?  Is it in the right location?  Did you edit but then forget to save it?  Can you temporarily add some obvious error to it, to test that the error is recognized?

I extended the question to add some more data to it. Regarding your question: yes, I believe the toml is being used, but how could I check?
for instance, when I use uv sync, it gest updated!

That's why I suggested adding some error to the file, so you can see if the error is recognized, thus confirming that the file is being used.

Yes, when I add some obvious error to the file, VScode is automatically marking the line as an error, but nothing happens besides that. Uv sync works as expected and the code runs all the same. Its only VScode complaining over the toml file.
How can I force this file to be used? Can I specify some path on the setting.json file to point for this toml file?

Have you installed Ruff through VS Code? If so you should find it in your VS Code settings and update there instead.

I believe the problem was that I had both a ruff.toml file and a pyproject.toml file. I deleted the ruff, which had nothing on it, and vscode automatically started ignoring the F401 and some others too (which were unimportant for me) as the pyproject.toml commanded. I guess the system was using the ruff and not the pyproject, or the ruff was overwriting the other... idk. But I deleted the ruff and worked. Does this makes any sense?
